# How to understand this frames per second cap

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a fps in a game but I don't understand the logic behind this code that i found. What is the point of the delta and the fact that it's greater than 1? Why do I have to subtract 1?

```
public void run() {

long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
double nsPerTick = 1000000000D / 60D; // how many nanoseconds per tick

int frames = 0;
int ticks = 0;

long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
double delta = 0;  // unprocessed nanoseconds. 

while(running){
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    delta += (now  - lastTime) / nsPerTick; //current time - lasttime
    lastTime = now; 

    while(delta >= 1){
        ticks++;
        tick();
        delta -= 1;
    }

    frames++;
    render();

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000){
        lastTimer += 1000; 
        System.out.println(frames + " " + ticks);
        frames = 0; 
        ticks = 0;
    }
}


}
```

Alternative:  Is the 1st approach better than this 2nd one from http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html?

```
while (true)
{
  double start = getCurrentTime();
  processInput();
  update();
  render();

  sleep(start + MS_PER_FRAME - getCurrentTime());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that every 1/60th second that passes between rendering represents one tick:

```
while (delta >= 1){
   ticks++;
   tick();
   delta -= 1 ;
}
```

This loop will run exactly `delta` times (which, as the comment in the code says, originally represents how many nanoseconds have passed by, but the division by `nsPerTick` converts to 1/60th seconds). So, if `delta` equals 5, the `tick()` function will run five times. That's all.

---

You could rewrite that bit like this, if it's more understandable to you:

```
for(int i=0;i<delta;i++) {
    tick(); //run this once per 1/60th second between frames
}
ticks = delta; //...and set 'ticks' equal to that number of 1/60th seconds
```

Comment: What do you think of this implementation as a cap?

Comment: @runners3431 right now it's not functional as a cap, but it could be with some changes, depending on how you wanted the cap to work.. I'd recommend giving [this page](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/) a look.

Comment: i added a 2nd implementation.  is it better than the first?

Answer (score 0):

nsPerTick is the frequency of frames.
1/nsPerTick is the period.

The Delta is the period * timePassed. Only after you complete a period (which means delta >= 1) you should render the next frame.

Then you substract 1 from delta because you want to know when to render the next frame.

Answer (score 0):

`delta` is a greek symbol used in math to denote change. 
`now` is an objective time, ie not time elapsed but and actual time such as 2:23:01:00 pm on oct 1st 2011. 
`delta` is a measure of how much time has *elapsed* between `now` i.e. the time at which your parent while loop does an individual iteration, and the contents of the variable `lastTime` which is infact the `now` of *previous* iteration of the while loop.
if the time difference between the two iterations is greater than 1, then your second while loop will iterate once for every integer *over* 1 your `delta` was.